# How do I force my Mac to log in to an account remotely?

Tags: terminal, command-line, ssh, user-account, login

It’s possible to restart a Mac from the command line (`sudo shutdown -r now`). It’s possible to log out from a Mac from the command line (`sudo pkill loginwindow`). But is it possible to force a Mac to log *in* from the command line? As in a full log in of an account, GUI-wise, not just logging in via SSH to the Mac via the Terminal.

Comment: What about connecting over screen sharing (the VNC protocol)?

Comment: I've not tested this with newer macOS versions. Apple may have locked this down requiring you to set it up in the GUI.  So changing the user that is automatic logging on may not be feasible.  This older article covers what's required to turn on the Automatic login setting from System Preferences -> Users & Groups -> Login Options. 

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/264068/can-autologin-be-set-up-from-the-command-line-how

Comment: Hopefully this isn’t an XY question and you need to do something else and this seems the first step to the final goal...

Comment: @bmike I don't know what an XY question is, but I want to be able to start Mail remotely after a restart, which requires logging in.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Will that work while logged out? In my experience, the connection dies when the user logs out, and there's no way to connect while the computer is on the login screen.

Comment: @JamesBrickley Yes, I know I can set the computer to auto-login. But for security reasons, I don't want to do that.

Comment: Sorry. It’s shorthand for a question about a solution. An intermediate step https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=XY+

Comment: @Calion I haven't tested with a generic VNC client, but with macOS' built-in "Screen Sharing" client, the connection will stay up as you log in & out. There's one exception, though: if you have FileVault turned on, you need to log in locally right after a reboot. That's because technically, after rebooting, FileVault presents a "pre-boot authentication" screen (*not* the regular login screen) before the OS (and the screen sharing service) can even start up.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

1. Enable FileVault so you can escrow user and password securely
2. `sudo fdesetup authrestart` sets the machine to restart and log in as the specified user after the restart.

This works for me remotely on new Macs with Big Sur. You may need `ssh` Or Apple Remote Desktop to log in remotely, but the above command works when I can’t be there to get past the FileVault log in screen and I’m remote and it generates a graphical log in from a remote `ssh` session.

Once the restart completes, Mail can start. Set it to launch at log in if you wish and you’re set. You don’t need auto log in since this works to make auto log in one time only.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted a simple way to initial a Filevault Restart on Macs so I created [FilevaultReboot](https://github.com/dieskim/FilevaultReboot)

A simple MacOS Menu Bar app that allows you to initiate a FileVault Restart. This app allows for easier / more automated “fdesetup authrestart” by simply entering your password.

This is especially useful for remotely managed systems that you want to reboot, that have FileVault enabled since it will allow the Mac to reboot and be managed after reboot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I created something like this for Remote Desktop to signing a xServe. We had more than 1 account, and we had to sign un with both username and password. I ran this remotely through the terminal to prior to pulling up the screen.

```
`osascript -e 'tell application "System Events"' -e 'keystroke "USERNAME"' -e 'keystroke tab' -e 'delay 0.5' -e 'keystroke "PASSWORD"' -e 'delay 3.5' -e 'keystroke return' -e 'keystroke return' -e 'end tell'`
```

Just replace the USERNAME and PASSWORD and that should work.  I have not tested this on a more recent OS, but I hope this helps.